# 'Cannot find module' when trying to unit test an import from a federated module (webpack 5) with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, webpack, jestjs

**Do you want to request a feature or report a bug?**
Report a bug

**What is the current behavior?**
https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack?at=5fad8fcdb86f64070448ee1c
The current behavior is that when running tests now 'imports' of components from federated modules being found because they're just a reference for webpack from the federated module entryPoint.js

**If the current behavior is a bug, please provide the steps to reproduce.**

Let's say we have an A repo with hosts other apps and modules and has an App.js file with the application page.
That App.js imports a component from a federated module.
Then we create an App.test.js to unit test the file and we try to mock the component from the federated module.
What is the expected behavior?
Unit tests should be able to pass with the mocked component.

Please mention other relevant information such as the browser version, Node.js version, webpack version, and Operating System.

```
Node v12.16.3
"webpack": "^5.4.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
"@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
"babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
jest@25.5.4
```

Example!
https://github.com/testacode/basic-host-remote

Comment: `Do you want to request a feature or report a bug? Report a bug`... erm. Stackoverflow is not a forum for reporting bugs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's clearly intended for the GitHub issue tracker and not as a question for StackOverflow

Comment: The guys at Jest told me to post a question over here @apokryfos

Comment: This is the example! https://github.com/testacode/basic-host-remote

Comment: The guys at Jest may have told you to post here but they definitely did not tell you to report a Jest bug in Stackoverflow (or if they did they should not have done). The most likely reason the told you to post here (or the reason you should be posting here) is if the issues is not with Jest itself but rather you have a question on how to use Jest under the curcumstances you described which means your question format needs to be completely different from what it is now to give us enough information to help answer